# Get sum of values in database

Tags: php, sum

Hi I have searched and tried some right answers in Stackoverflow, but none works.

I tried

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Temp";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$qty= 0;
While ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) {
$qty += $num['Price'];
}
echo $qty;
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(Price) AS value_sum FROM Temp');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
```

Both saying

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource

Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Does the table `Temp` exist? Have you tried `var_dump(mysql_error())`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: @Kolink yes it does, I even tried 'SELECT SUM(Price) AS value_sum FROM Temp' inside the database, it gives me the right answer

Comment: Have you used `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` correctly?

Comment: @Kolink yes, the connection does work. This is just a part of my php code, others are work fine

Comment: try it with fetch_array instead and cast it before doing math actions.. $qty += (int)($num['Price']);

Comment: What about the `mysql_error()`? Does it show any error message?

Comment: @dyoser thanks for helping I just tried  mysqli instead and it works :-)

Comment: @Kolink thanks for helping I just tried  mysqli instead and it works :-)

Comment: @JamesChen Don't tag everyone with same reply. =)